# Did the demon Hiranyaksha receive Andhaka from Lord Shiva?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, parvati, varaha

If Hiranyaksha received Andhaka from Lord Shiva, does that mean Shiva and Parvati were already married long before Lord Vishnu's Varaha Avatar where Hiranyaksha was killed?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Lord Shiva [gave](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226183.html) Andhaka to Hiranyaksha before Varaha Avatar.

> Sanatkumāra said:—
> 38. On hearing these words of the king, the kind-hearted Śiva was satisfied and spoke thus—“O ruler of Daityas, there may not be a son
> born of your semen. But I shall grant you a son.
>
> 39. **My son Andhaka has a prowess equal to yours. He cannot be defeated by any. You choose him as your son.** Cast off your distress and accept
>     him as your son.”
> 40. After saying this, the delighted lord gave the son to Hiraṇyākṣa.[10] Śiva, the great soul, the primordial lord of Bhūtas,
>     the destroyer of Tripuras, the fierce god went away, accompanied by
>     Pārvatī.
> 41. After getting a son from Śiva that Daitya circumambulated Śiva and worshipped him with many hymns. Joyously the noble Asura returned to
>     kingdom.
> 42. **Having obtained a son from Śiva, the demon of great and fierce valour conquered all the gods and took the earth to Pātāla.**
> 43. **Then the gods, sages and the Siddhas propitiated Viṣṇu of infinite vigour in the form of a Boar** that constituted all sacrifices and all
>     beings and was terrific in form.
>
> 44-46. He split the earth by beating and striking with his snout and
> entered Pātāla. He powdered hundreds of Daityas with his nose and the
> formidable curved fangs. He smashed the armies of the Asuras by
> kicking with his legs dazzling like lightning. He had a wonderfully
> fierce refulgence. With his Sudarśana dazzling like a crore of suns he
> chopped off the burning head of Hiraṇyākṣa and reduced the wicked
> Daityas to ashes. He was then delighted to crown his son Andhaka as
> the king of Daityas.
>
> 47. He returned to his abode. He lifted up the earth from the Pātāla by means of his fangs. He sustained the Earth as before.
> 48. Eulogised by the gods, the delighted sages, and Brahmā, lord Viṣṇu of huge body who had assumed the form of a Boar finished the task and
>     returned to his abode.
> 49. **When Hiraṇyākṣa the king of Asuras was killed by Viṣṇu assuming the form of a Boar**,[11] the gods, sages and other living beings became
>     happy.